# How can I make a footer to be displayed after the whole content ends?

Tags: css

```html
i am using ionic,hence i have a   code something like this                        <ion-header></ion-header>
<ion-content>
<div *ngFor="let publisher of publishers" class="contentspacing">
    <div class="border-div">
        <div class="chkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBoxSize"                                       id="instituteId{{publisher.ID}}"         [checked]="publisher.preferenceValue || publisher.isSelected " (click)="capturepublishers($event,publisher.ID, publisher.Name, publisher)" />
        </div>
        <div class="listName taxonomyTitle">{{publisher.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footerContainer">
    <strong>Copyright &copy, Synger All Rights Reserved</strong>
</footer>
</ion-content>
```

```css
/* The Footer Css */
.footerContainer {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}


/* The ContentHolder that contain dynamic data */
.contentspacing {
  margin-bottom: 100% !important;
}
```

The content displayed are in dynamic form in all pages of my website. what css I have to apply so that the footer is displayed only after the whole content ends

Comment: you don't have to add any css to place it at the bottom if your css is proper for the previous element

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: Above I have added the css .Please look into it and help me out

Comment: can you show your html code @KANeha

Comment: ya I have added the Html code too

Comment: Is anyone there to help me out in this

Comment: @KANeha you want footer to be fixed at the bottom?

Comment: No not the fixed one.i want it at the bottom of dynamic content to be present at the end of page

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:fixed;bottom:0;` for your footer class. And also I adjusted the content spacing margin. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```css
body {
  position:relative;
}
/* The Footer Css */
footer.footerContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}


/*The ContentHolder that contain dynamic data */
.contentspacing {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let publisher of publishers" class="contentspacing">
    <div class="border-div">
        <div class="chkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkBoxSize" id="instituteId{{publisher.ID}}" [checked]="publisher.preferenceValue || publisher.isSelected " (click)="capturepublishers($event,publisher.ID, publisher.Name, publisher)" />
        </div>
        <div class="listName taxonomyTitle">{{publisher.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footerContainer">
    <strong>Copyright &copy, Synger All Rights Reserved</strong>
</footer>
```

Try the updated one. This one is default html format.

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">header</div>
   <div id="body">body</div>
   <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working .Its making the footer hanging at the middle of page

Comment: Updated the code with body `position:relative;`. try now

Comment: i have updated the code above.Please look into it.I am using ionic3

Comment: I think `position: fixed;` for footer might work  for all html code.

Comment: but it will fix the footer at a place that i dont want

Comment: `position:absolute` for footer is the alternative solution. Try the second snippet.